# How to reorganise the data to make a data frame or contingency in R?

Tags: r

Suppose, I have the data:

```
  V1   V2 Frequency
  17 49334        1
  17   500        9
  17 64831        1
   6    13        2
  17 50831        6
  17 64756        1
  17 55791        2
  17 60986        1
   6  9100    14564
   6    53      341
  17 62408        1
  17    53 21693735
```

I would like to know if there is any function in R that will allow me to transform the data into a contingency table / data frame such that the data will look like :

```
    V2
V1         13       53      500     9100    49334    50831    55791    60986
  6         2      341        0    14564        0        0        0        0
  17        0 21693735        9        0        1        6        2        1
```

In this case, the function should be able to identify multiple occurrences of "6" and "17" in V1 and "53" in V2. If there is no such function, can someone show me a smart way to write a function that will achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `xtabs`:

```
xtabs(Frequency ~ V1 + V2, data=<your data frame>)
```